# How to Create a new blank Record without it showing the previous data from the previous record?

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2013, multiple-records

I keep trying to create a new record expecting a new blank form to show up but all of the info from the previous form shows up.

I need a blank form to enter data but i also need to save all of my previous forms. Overall, I want to keep adding onto my records. But somehow it won't let me.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly you open a form but it is showing the data you previously entered? if it is that you want avoid seeing the previous data and just have a blank for for entry that you should set the form properties `Data Entry` to `Yes`

[image]

Comment: In order to access the form's property you have to go to the forms design mode. I realize that you are new here so remember to indicate the response that answered your question for the benefit of others searching for answers here. :)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whether or not you have a bound form, Kefash' answer could work.
If you have an unbound form however, it will not.

If you do have an unbound form, the simplest way is to just loop through all the controls and empty them.
For example:

```
Private Sub save_Click()
Dim ctl As Control
    For Each ctl In Me.Controls
    Select Case ctl.ControlType
    Case acListBox
        If Len(ctl.ControlSource) = 0 Then
            ctl.Value = Null
        End If
    Case acCheckBox
        ctl.Value = 0
    Case acTextBox
        ctl.value = ""
    End Select
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: The code must be added in your visual basic, but seeing as how you have never worked with code before, this is not your solution.
I would try to follow kefash' solution. Besides that, you can also add pre programmed buttons in the design view of your form, one of which gives you the possibility to add a new record. Good luck!