# Open a Form with ID MS Access

Tags: forms, vba, ms-access-2010

I've read a few of the threads that address this issue, but I'm still having an error where the form opens to a blank record.

My setup is that I have a "Contact File" form that displays general contact information on an individual from a "Master Contact Database" table. At the bottom of this form, I have a subform that displays case information for that individual and also allows the user to create new cases. This information is properly storing in the "Casefile Information" table I've created in Access.

However, when I try to open the "Casefile Information" form, with a button and a text field on the "Contact File" form, it brings up a blank record. I've tried using MS Access' built in "button" creation tool to create a macro as well as the following VBA:

```
Private Sub Command112_Click()
DoCmd.OpenForm "Casefile Information", , , "CASEID = " & Me.Text98
End Sub
```

I've also tried this method:

```
Private Sub Command112_Click()
Dim RecordID As Integer
RecordID = Me.Text98
DoCmd.OpenForm "Casefile Information", , , "CASEID = " & RecordID
End Sub
```

- Text98 is the text box on the "Contact File" form.
- The CASEID Is 8 numeric characters, the primary key for that table, user entered but with no duplicates allowed.
- The second example above returns an error (6) on the RecordID=Me.Text98 line.

For whatever reason, there is ONE record in the database that this works properly but no other contacts and no other case files for that contact will load correctly.

Thanks!

Comment: What happens when you use a value? Eg `docmd.OpenForm "Casefile Information",,,"CASEID=" & 12345678` Look up a case ID first. If that works, step though and check the value you are passing. Make sure that CaseId is a numeric field.

Comment: If I put the value `10070114`, which appears in the database, in `Text98` (the text box that the button pulls information from) and change the button command to `DoCmd.OpenForm "Casefile Information" , , , "CASEID=" & 10070114` then it opens correctly. CASEID is a numeric field in the table it is stored.

Comment: Try `..."CASEID = " & Me.Text98`, but put in a break and check the value of Text98, it may not have the correct value. Have you considered a combobox to find records, it is very easy to code, because there are wizards for finding records with combos on bound forms. You only have to be careful to clear the cmbo after you find the record so the user is not confused when navigating.

Comment: I not believe that `.. "CASEID = " & RecordID` will ever work.

Comment: Tried the combobox strategy, I like the appearance better and will likely use it moving forward; however, the blank form issue is still present.

Comment: Did you step though and get the value of Text98?

Comment: I setup the combobox to pull the values from the `Casefile Information` database and the coded the button to pull the stored value from the combobox and open the form based on that value (generically named `combobox113`). In that combobox I displayed both columns 1 (CASEID) and 2 (SHORT_DESC) but bound the value to column 1 so that it would carry the CASEID value to open the form.

Answer (score 0):

You have to ensure the the `Casefile Information` form is set to Data Entry = No otherwise it will come up blank all the time. see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24493903/how-to-create-a-new-blank-record-without-it-showing-the-previous-data-from-the-p/24497339#24497339)

as for the error you received you may be having some datatype miss match or [overflow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264525(v=vs.60).aspx)

Comment: The Casefile Information form is set to Data Entry = No. The problem is still present.

Comment: I started getting an overflow error (runtime 6). Changed the data type to Long and it worked once before beginning to pull blank forms again.

Answer (score 0):

I setup the combobox to pull the values from the Casefile Information database and the coded the button to pull the stored value from the combobox and open the form based on that value (generically named combobox113). In that combobox I displayed both columns 1 (CASEID) and 2 (SHORT_DESC) but bound the value to column 1 so that it would carry the CASEID value to open the form.

It was a work around, but got the job done for the time being.